# Arrows appearing in li of html

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, adjustment

We are trying to add a new pricing table to our website but when we add it we get some random arrows appear?

What do i need to do to remove these arrows?

Thanks.

Link here: http://www.towersdesign.co.uk/price-error/

Ben

Comment: Maybe you could add some code (HTML / CSS) to help us help you. I'll give you a hint, it's a `:before` pseudo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this CSS found in *style.css* on line 554

```
media="all"
.main ul li:before, .more:before, .comment-reply-link:before, .comment-edit-link:before {
/* content: "g"; */
/* font-family: 'bulletsregular'; */
```

If you need the bullets elsewhere, see @Hive's solution

Comment: hi, i have gone with yours, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a font wich is added on a pseudo element:
.main ul li:before, .more:before, .comment-reply-link:before, .comment-edit-link:before.

line 554

fontname: bulletsregular

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.main ul li:before, h1 span, h2 span, h3 span, h4 span, .highlight, h5, h6, cite, h1:after, h2:after, h3:after, .main-container a:hover, .more:before, ol > li:before, .cta a:hover, .error[generated=true], span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip, div.wpcf7-response-output, .footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr > td.expand:before, ul.social-link a:hover, #nav ul li a:hover:before, ul.page-numbers .current, #nav li a:hover, li.current-menu-ancestor a, #nav li li.current_page_item > a, ul.comments h5 a, .comment-reply-link:before, .comment-edit-link:before, #cancel-comment-reply-link:before, .link-pages p a, #wp-calendar a, .logo-text:after, .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li a:hover, .statistics li h4, ul.filters li.active a, .toggle-btn.active, .accordion-btn.active, .sc_accordion-btn.active, ul.tab-nav li.active, h3.v_nav.v_active, .foot-widgets a:hover, .foot-widgets a:hover b, .tweets cite:before, li.tweet .meta:before, .icon-thirds li:hover em:before, .boxed ul.social-link a:hover, .boxed h5, .sitemap li a:hover, .shipping_calculator h2 a, .woocommerce table.cart a.remove, .woocommerce #content table.cart a.remove, .woocommerce-page table.cart a.remove, .woocommerce-page #content table.cart a.remove, .woocommerce form .form-row .required, .woocommerce-page form .form-row .required, .woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a:hover, .woocommerce #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a:hover, .woocommerce-page div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a:hover, .woocommerce-page #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a:hover, .woocommerce .star-rating span:before, .woocommerce-page .star-rating span:before, .woocommerce div.product .stock, .woocommerce #content div.product .stock, .woocommerce-page div.product .stock, .woocommerce-page #content div.product .stock, .woocommerce div.product .out-of-stock, .woocommerce #content div.product .out-of-stock, .woocommerce-page div.product .out-of-stock, .woocommerce-page #content div.product .out-of-stock {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the bullets?

Answer (score 0):

Add following style to your stylesheet or on page.

if you add in stylesheet it may not visible to rest of the whole application where have you mapped that stylesheet. if you want to remove from all over webapp, add following style in CSS. but if you just want to remove from this page only add this style on page only.

```
#plans li:before {
   content: "" !important;
}
```

[image: See the Screenshot]

Comment: That is not the only place they are